# Как изменить стиль столбца/строки с помощью Qt Style Sheets?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qss, qtablewidget, qstyleditemdelegate

1)Подскажите, каким образом можно установить фон для 1 столбца/строки? 
Есть ли возможность не создавать QFrame для каждой ячейки столбца/строки?

2)Каким образом можно установить только вертикальные границы столбцов в таблице?

**UPD**:
С кодом в общем то проблем нет, так как его нет :( Я не могу найти в документации каким образом с помощью таблицы стилей или каких-либо методов можно реализовать заливку одного столбца/строки и как можно разделить только по вертикали. Таким образом выглядит моя таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для левых двух столбцов создавался QFrame, в правом ничего. Можно заметить небольшие пробелы между ячейками, поэтому заливка QFrame не подходит

```
def _createtable(self):

                table = QTableWidget(43,5)
                sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                                   QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
                sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
                sizePolicy.setVerticalPolicy(0)
                sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(table.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
                table.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
                table.setMinimumSize(QSize(400,0))
                table.setMaximumSize(QSize(2000,2000))
                table.setSizeIncrement(QSize(0,0))
                table.setLayoutDirection(Qt.LeftToRight)
                table.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
                table.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
                table.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
                table.setShowGrid(False)
                table.setGridStyle(Qt.SolidLine)
                table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
                table.setObjectName("Table")
                table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels([
                                            'Product','Base output','Base\nconsumption',
                                            'Productivity','Buildings\nRequired'
                                            ])
                table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode( QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)               
                table.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
                for row in range(table.rowCount()):
                    gbox = QGridLayout()
                    framebox = QFrame()
                    framebox.setLayout(gbox)
                    table.setCellWidget(row,2,framebox)
                    hbox8 = QHBoxLayout()
                    hbox8.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
                    framebox2 = QFrame()
                    framebox2.setLayout(hbox8)
                    table.setCellWidget(row,3,framebox2)
                    hbox9 = QHBoxLayout()
                    framebox3 = QFrame()
                    framebox3.setLayout(hbox9)
                    table.setCellWidget(row,0,framebox3)
                    farmer = QLabel()
                    farmer.setPixmap(QPixmap(':Portrait_Farmer').scaled(25,25))
                    worker = QLabel()
                    worker.setPixmap(QPixmap(':Portrait_Worker').scaled(25,25))
                    artisan = QLabel()
                    artisan.setPixmap(QPixmap(':Portrait_Artisan').scaled(25,25))
                    engineer = QLabel()
                    engineer.setPixmap(QPixmap(':Portrait_Engineer').scaled(25,25))
                    investor = QLabel()
                    investor.setPixmap(QPixmap(':Portrait_Investor').scaled(25,25))
                    tourist = QLabel()
                    tourist.setPixmap(QPixmap(':Portrait_Tourist').scaled(25,25))
                    scholar = QLabel()
                    scholar.setPixmap(QPixmap(':Portrait_Scholar').scaled(25,25))
                    for pics in (farmer,worker,artisan,engineer,investor,tourist,scholar):
                        pics.setStyleSheet("background-color: ")
                    column_pop = column1.pop(0)
                    pb = QPushButton(QIcon(":"+ column_pop),'')
                    pb.setMinimumSize(35,35)
                    pb.setMaximumSize(35,35)
                    pb.setStyleSheet("background-color: brown")
                    hbox9.addWidget(pb)             
                    widget = QTableWidgetItem(column2.pop(0))   
                    widget.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter) 
                    table.setItem(row%60,1,widget)  
                    a = column3.pop(0)
```

А это часть кода для таблицы стилей:

```
.QFrame {
    background-color: #664127;
    border-radius: ;
}
QTableView {
    column3-background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0.5, y2: 0.5,
                                stop: 0 #FF92BB, stop: 1 white);
}
#Table {
    background-color: #805130;
    font-size: 20px;
}

QHeaderView::section {
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1.25, stop:0 #563721, stop: 0.6 #664127, stop:1 #805130);
    color: #e1e5cf;
    border-right: 2px solid #ced2bc;
    border-top: 2px solid #ced2bc;
    border-left: 2px solid #ced2bc;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: Regular;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему или код, в котором вам надо реализовать то, что вы задумали..

Comment: пожалуйста, покажите код, который у вас есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1 .** Вы должны научиться составлять **минимально воспроизводимые примеры**,
а не прилагать какие-то части кода.

**Минимальный** - это пример, который содержит код,
который касается только текущей проблемы.
Не надо публиковать какую-то логику, например работы с БД,
если это никаким образом не связано с проблемой.

**Воспроизводимый** - это значит, что ваш пример просто копируется и запускается,
и после запуска сразу видна проблема, о которой вы спрашиваете.

**2.** Вопрос должен касаться только ОДНОЙ проблемы.

---

Возможное решение того что вы хотите сделать:

Класс [**QStyledItemDelegate**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html) предоставляет средства отображения и редактирования элементов данных из модели.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class HighlightDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(HighlightDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        if index.column() == 2:    
            option.backgroundBrush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("#F7A76C"))
        
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        super(HighlightDelegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)
        line = QtCore.QLine(option.rect.topRight(), option.rect.bottomRight())
        painter.save()
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor("#FF00E4"), 4)) 
        painter.drawLine(line)
        painter.restore()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(5, 5)
        
        delegate = HighlightDelegate(self.tableWidget)
        self.tableWidget.setItemDelegate(delegate)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.tableWidget)


QSS = '''
QHeaderView::section:horizontal { 
    border: 0px;
    border-right: 4px solid #FF00E4
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(QSS)                               
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(600, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Rett_oo что не так?

Comment: Все так, только сейчас увидел ответ. Благодарю!